# Playing a MIDI file clogs up the heap with millions of com.sun.media.sound.ModelSource[]

Tags: java, audio, midi

As the title says, i have a game that plays a MIDI file in the background.
This appears to create millions of instances of com.sun.media.sound.ModelSource[], taking up lots of RAM, causing GC lag spikes and probably clearing some SoftReferences (i'm not sure if they do).
I don't have any other sound related code and it also does not appear to be related to the size of the soundbank I use.
Is there any way to improve the memory footprint?

My code:

```
public class MusicPlayer {
    private Sequencer player;
    private Synthesizer synth;
    private Soundbank bank;
    private boolean paused = false;
    private boolean ready = false;

    public MusicPlayer() {
        try {
            // Initialize MIDI output
            player = MidiSystem.getSequencer(false);
            synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
            bank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/to/soundbank.sf2")));
            player.open();
            synth.open();
            player.getTransmitter().setReceiver(synth.getReceiver());
            synth.loadAllInstruments(bank);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("MUSIC INITIALIZATION ERROR: \n" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts playing a new track
     */
    public void play(String name) {
        try {
            Sequence track = Loader.getSong(name);
            player.stop();
            player.setSequence(track);
            player.setMicrosecondPosition(0); // Rewind if needed
            player.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            paused = false;
            ready = true;
            player.start(); // And here we go!
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("MUSIC PLAY ERROR: \n" + e.toString());
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pauses the currently playing track
     */
    public void pause() {
        if (!paused && ready) {
            player.stop();
            paused = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unpauses the currently playing track
     */
    public void unpause() {
        if (paused && ready) {
            player.start();
            paused = false;
        }
    }
}
```